# Sort a strings array in ascending order with a word priority

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

For the following array

```
[
  { name: '4K UHD', commentator: 'Ali' },
  { name: 'English 1 HD', commentator: 'Ahmed' },
  { name: 'English 3 HD', commentator: 'Ahmed' },
  { name: 'Premium 1 HD', commentator: 'Ali' },
  { name: 'Premium 2 HD', commentator: 'Ahmed' },
]
```

I want to sort it so that objects with a `name` of **Premium** (as the last two objects) comes first but also in ascending order.

The desired result is this

```
[
  { name: 'Premium 1 HD', commentator: 'Ali' },
  { name: 'Premium 2 HD', commentator: 'Ahmed' },
  { name: '4K UHD', commentator: 'Ali' },
  { name: 'English 1 HD', commentator: 'Ahmed' },
  { name: 'English 3 HD', commentator: 'Ahmed' },
]

// or like this
[
  { name: 'Premium 1 HD', commentator: 'Ali' },
  { name: 'Premium 2 HD', commentator: 'Ahmed' },
  { name: 'English 1 HD', commentator: 'Ahmed' },
  { name: 'English 3 HD', commentator: 'Ahmed' },
  { name: '4K UHD', commentator: 'Ali' },
]
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a custom compare function

```
const cmp = (a, b) => {
    const pa = a.name.startsWith("Premium");
    const pb = b.name.startsWith("Premium");
    return 
        pa !== pb 
          // comparing Premium vs non-Premium, Premium "wins"
        ? (pa ? -1 : 1) 
          // everything else (i.e. Prem vs Prem or non-Prem vs non-Prem)
        : a.name.localeCompare(b.name); 
};

dataArray.sort(cmp);
```

You can ensure that all strings starting with `Premium` are moved to the top of the sort, while ensuring that the sort order is retained among the `Premium` and non-`Premium` "groups".

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly! But what if I wanted to add another string to be pirotized? i.e how to generalize the function to do the same but instead of 'Premium' it gets an array of strings?

Comment: @MuhammadMahmoud I have you covered. A while back, I wrote a library that would allow you to make any kind of prioritization. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-comparer-builder . Here, for instance, you could create a compare function as follows: `comparerBuilder().sortKey(({name}) => name.split(" ")[0] === "Premium" ? 0 : 1).thenBy(({name}) => name).build()`

Comment: This is great I'll have a look at it. Thank you!

Comment: Came back to say that it worked as I wanted and it's far more intuitive. Thank you again

Comment: @MuhammadMahmoud Thanks for the praise. Mostly nobody uses the stuff I write :D

Comment: You'll get the recognition sooner or later don't worry about it just keep up the good work xd

Answer (score 0):

Try Decending order:

```js
array.sort((a, b) => a.name < b.name ? 1 : -1)
```

Comment: OP has been explicit that they want to maintain an ascending order, so this doesn't work.